# WHM Basic Setup IPV4 Address

Tags: dns, ip-address, nameserver, whm

I want to hide with embarassment as I ask this but I am not sure where to look elsewhere for help with the question!

I've seen "*The IPv4 address (only one address) to use to set up shared IPv4 virtual hosts."
We strongly recommend that you only specify an IPv4 address that you have associated with this server*.".

...Within Basic WHM setup.

Now, in my web browser, let's say I have https://22.23.231.23.host.myvpsserver.net:2083/cpsess.... as my WHM URL.

and I have, available (I've deliberately jumbled them up abit for you experts who will probably spot that but at least we can refer to them!),

92.24.244.44 - Primary
92.24.212.21
92.24.213.22

2a00:2369:22a:82a0::
2a00:2369:229:4b90::
2a00:2369:226:2c80::

I get these "available" IPs from my VPS management area. There is no mention of the IP I actually log in to WHM with (22.23.231.23) within the VPS Management area.

How can I make maximum use of these please and should I be putting this random 22.23.231.23 that I log into WHM with within Basic Webhost Manager Setup or one of the other IPv4s?

How can the other IPs be used and how do they interact with cPanel presuming they do so, simply by pointing at my VPS. Are there other steps I need to perform? The fact that cPanel has picked another IP seems to be telling me that the one from the WHM URL should not be used.

I also noticed that cPanel allocates very random looking nameservers by default. Is this dummy information intended for replacing please or do they just work out of the packet? If so, i've ended up replacing them and I shouldn't have done!

Many thanks.